# @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) Works with JpaRepository findOne() but not with findAll()

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a class with `@ManyToOne` relation

```
@Table(name = "answers")
public class Answer implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "answer_id")
  private Long answerId;    

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "category_id",referencedColumnName = "category_id")
  @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
  private Category category;
}
```

And simple repository

```
@Repository
public interface AnswerRepository extends JpaRepository<Answer, Long> {
}
```

In my Answer Controller i have two methods one which returns single Answer by id using `AnswerRepository.findOne()` and second returning list of all answers using `AnswerRepository.findAll()`

The problem is `@Fetch` works with `findOne()` perfectly, (checked both with JOIN and SELECT which changed query from join to two separate queries),
but with `.findAll()` it doesn't work, I'm always getting one main query + n extra queries for each category needed.

I would like `findAll()` to also be affected by `@Fetch` or some other way to not get n queries, as in current way it is slow and making tons of queries to get list of answers, but i can't find any way to get it working.

I really appreciate any answers. Thank you for help.

(Shortened to id fields queries)
find one query:

```
select 
  answer0_.answer_id as answer_i1_0_0_,
  .
  category1_.category_id as category1_1_1_,
  .
from answers answer0_ 
inner join categories category1_ on 
  answer0_.category_id=category1_.category_id 
where answer0_.answer_id=?
```

findAll queries:

```
select answer0_.answer_id as answer_i1_0_,
   answer0_.category_id as category6_0_
from answers answer0_

select category0_.category_id as category1_1_0_
from categories category0_ 
where category0_.category_id=?

select category0_.category_id as category1_1_0_
from categories category0_ 
where category0_.category_id=?

select category0_.category_id as category1_1_0_
from categories category0_
where category0_.category_id=?

select category0_.category_id as category1_1_0_
from categories category0_
where category0_.category_id=?

select category0_.category_id as category1_1_0_
from categories category0_
where category0_.category_id=?

select category0_.category_id as category1_1_0_
from categories category0_
where category0_.category_id=?
```

Comment: I managed to force join by using 
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = { "category" })
    List<Answer> findAll();

but i'm not sure if this is right solution for my problem, and why @Fetch doesn't work with findAll()

Comment: afaik Spring Data ignores the FetchMode as it's an hibernate annotation...
NamedEntityGraph is the right way to go (or you specify the fetching in a custom query instead of using the findAll)